# Multiple axis voting system (star rating)

Tags: 6, rating

I tried [Multiple Axis Voting System using Drupal FiveStar and Computed Field](http://blog.attomsoft.com/drupal/108/multiple-axis-voting-system-using-drupal-fivestar-and-computed-field), but I am not able to understand the below 2 points:

1. Add a node reference field to the voting node type, make the targeted node type selected.
2. Setup the voting(aka.review) node type, add all needed field and fivestar fields for multiple axis voting. Remember set the "target" option to #3 field.

May anyone help me understanding this?

Comment: Also just an FYI, this is possible with fivestar 6.x-2.x and 7.x-2.x without any extra modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate).

> This module provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments.
>
> Administrators can add multiple widgets. By default, there are 6 widget types to choose from.

Comment: This works great for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind this technique, is to have a node that can be reviewed, and then create review nodes that contain the votes.

The first step you list, requires you to add a node reference field on the review node, where you can select nodes of the type that can be reviewed. That will enable uses to select what they are reviewing.

The second step is to setup fivestar for the review node. You need to add the axis that should be voted on, and which users will be able to set when creating the node.